# How to append data to a div in client side When server is pushing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

   for(i=0; i<10; i++){ 
    io.emit('notification', i);
  }
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

```html
  <body>

  <style type="text/css">
   
   .chatting {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
   }
  </style>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('notification', function(msg){
       alert(msg);
   
      });
    </script>

 <div class = chatting></div>    

  </body>
```

I am just trying to append data to a div in client side when the server is pushing some value. How to do that. Here is my code. The alert is working fine. But I need the Numbers are inserted to the div. Every time server pushing, the number should be changed automatically, like notifications on Facebook.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <script>
      var socket = io();
      function appendNotification(notification){
         document.getElementById("notifications").innerHTML = "<div>" +  notification + "</div>";
      }
      socket.on('notification', function(msg){
        appendNotification(msg);
      });
    </script>
    ADD the id to your html
    <div class="chatting" id="notifications"></div>
```

Comment: I was tried. But its not working. I am not an experienced person. So Problem is mine or not, I couldn't find the answer with above problem. Please help me if u could. Thanks

Comment: Now its working. But its showing all the numbers at a time. I just need every time the numbers change inside of the div, like, 1 then 2 then 3 continusily. Like notifications showing on the Facebook even refresh the browser. Thank you

Comment: Updated the answer again

Answer (score 1):

Try with this on your code. I hope this help.

```
<script>
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('notification', function(msg){
        var div = document.getElementsByClassName('chatting');
        div.innerHTML += msg;
      });
</script>
```

Comment: But it not showing the numbers inside of the div. Thanks for the help

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . This is the error. I cannot find the problem. Because I am not expert in coding. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var socket = io();
      socket.on('notification', function(msg){
       alert(msg);
     $('.chatting').text(msg);
      });
});
</script>
```

```html
 <body>

  <style type="text/css">
   
   .chatting {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
   }
  </style>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
 <div class="chatting"></div>    

  </body>
```